# SBT - include dependency for everything but test

Tags: sbt

I have a dependency (stagemonitor.org) that I want to include for everything except "test" and "test:test". How do I include a dependency for everything but "test"? I'm using SBT 0.13.8.

Thanks,

Johan

Comment: Can you provide a failure-reproducing use case to work against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to exclude things manually via `managedClasspath in Test`.
Check out `-=` operator we are adding on 0.13.9-RC1.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out when 0.13.9 is out. I solved it by muting the library under test.